# php notice undefined index how to get rid of

Tags: php

I'm getting a `Notice: Undefined index` when I load my page at every of the following lines. The code works like expected only the source file (the html online) gives this notice. I'm new to php but I learned that a notice needs to be fixed if possible.

```
<select name='table'>
    <option value='table1' <?php if($_GET['table']=="Table1"){echo "SELECTED";}?> >page1</option>
    <option value='table2' <?php if($_GET['table']=="Table2"){echo "SELECTED";}?> >page2</option>
    <option value='table3' <?php if($_GET['table']=="Table3"){echo "SELECTED";}?> >page3</option>
    <option value='table4' <?php if($_GET['table']=="Table4"){echo "SELECTED";}?> >page4</option>
    <option value='table5' <?php if($_GET['table']=="Table5"){echo "SELECTED";}?> >page5</option>
</select>
```

I tried to add an isset `if(isset($_get` but that did not work. Is there a way to get rid of this notice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `isset` function to check if the key exists:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['table']) && $_GET['table'] =="Table1"){echo "SELECTED";}?>
```

You mention you tried to use isset, so im guessing you got your syntax wrong

Comment: thank you. this worked. Your guess was correct. I used it the wrong way. I thought I needed isset so i tried `<?php if(isset($_GET['table'])=="Table1"){echo "SELECTED";}?>` and i tried `<?php if(isset($_GET['table']=="Table1")){echo "SELECTED";}?>`. i couldn't find the answer on this site or on the internet so thank you.